# Bluemixのディスクサイズの上限

Tags: node.js, bluemix

Node.jsランタイム環境の最大ディスクサイズはいくつでしょうか
動画データをアップロードしようとしています

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ディスクサイズはcfコマンドで最大2GBまで指定可能です。

動画データを保管するとのことですが、Bluemixではランタイムのローカルファイルシステムにはデータを保管しないのが原則です。ローカルのデータは揮発性であり再ステージすると失われる、スケールアウトさせたときに不整合が起こる等の懸念があります。
動画ファイルはObject Storageに格納し、メタデータはNoSQL DBのCloudantに格納するといった構成を検討されてはいかがでしょうか。